# Setting conditional font size in kivy language?

Tags: kivy

I have a custom Button Widget that's being defined as a python class and in kivy markup. I'd like the font to be set to a default size (let's say `'50sp'`) unless a `font_size` parameter is passed to the Button, in which case, the font size should be whatever value was passed. The code is as follows:

python:

```
class Custom_Button(Button):
    ...
```

kivy:

```
<Custom_Button>:
    ...
    font_size = self.font_size if self.font_size else '50sp'
```

The issue is that it never gets to the '50sp' clause. If a font_size parameter is not passed to an instance of the Button object when it's created, kivy's default font size will be utilized. Any idea of what causes this behavior and suggestions of what to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set self.font_size to be 50sp? That way it's always the default, unless the user provided something.

```
class Custom_Button(Button):
    font_size = NumericProperty('50sp')
```

You could also do this in kv language, I think a user provided value would still override whatever default you provide here:

```
<Custom_Button>:
    font_size: sp(50)
```

Comment: Thanks, inclement. That's what I was trying to accomplish. It appears that my original question was based on a misinterpretation of the app's behavior. Long day of coding...